# Pycharm doesn't recognize ipython in virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, ipython, pycharm

I made a virtualenv based on Python3.2 and installed ipython 0.12 in it. Pycharm is supposed to recognize ipython automatically, but it doesn't:
[image: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-5452184-25073/Schermafbeelding+2012-02-18+om+10.44.22.png]

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue with PyCharm not recognizing my iPython install. I am running EPD 7.2.2 on OS X 10.7.3 with PyCharm 2.0.1, and using virtualenvwrapper.

The workaround that worked for me was to reinstall iPython after creating my virtualenv.

Try running this:

```
workon <myvirtualenv>
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
```

Then add your  directory as a "Python Interpreter" in PyCharm, and setting the "Project Interpreter" to .

Curious to hear if that works for you too.

Cheers,

Nolan

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In my Pycharm,I use the fellow:

```
workon flask
pip install ipython
```

and then in the Project Interpreter,you can see the package `ipython v.2.3.1` display.